# How to detect "movement" of 2-in-1 hinge in a laptop

Tags: kernel, touch-screen

So, I have both Lenovo yoga 510 and Lenovo yoga 2(they have the same up-to-date fedora installation). Now, as some may know, they are 2-in-1 laptops, which means that their hinge can be rotated in 360 degrees. When rotating the yoga 2, gnome turns off the keyboard and the touchpad, so there must be some way to detect when the hinges are rotated. Is there some way to detect this from userspace(may some file in /sys/)? I need it to write some scripts that should be run when I rotate the screen.

Comment: Run `evtest` as root, pick in turn all event sources that look promising, see if you get an event when you rotate the hinge. If that doesnt work, try to look for ACPI events with `acpi_listen` etc.

Comment: @dirkt I tried both commands, but neither works. What other events can I try listening for?

Comment: Huh. The next step would be to go through `dmesg` and/or `/var/log/syslog` after boot, and look for anything interesting that stands out. Put it into a pastebin, post a link.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw the event, it seems that the linux drivers still don't support it, I can see(in dmesg) ideapad_laptop: Unknown event 10 just when I flip the screen. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug for [ideapad-laptop](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=ideapad-laptop) on the kernel tracker list, and mention that you received event `10` when flipping the screen. The event is supposed to be reported in [`ideapad_acpi_notify`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c), if I read the code correctly via `/dev/input`.

It's requires only a simple fix to get it working again.

There's already a bug that [seems related](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109501), maybe piggyback on this one.